# Can code formatting lead to change in object file content?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, formatting

I have run though a code formatting tool to my c++ files. It is supposed to make only formatting changes. Now when I built my code, I see  that size of object file for some source files have changed. Since my files are very big and tool has changed almost every line, I dont know whether it has done something disastrous. Now i am worried to check in this code to repo as it might lead to runtime error due to formatting tool.  My question is , will the size of object file be changed , if code formatting is changed.?

Comment: Before you check in a change today that modifies every source line, do bear in mind that if someone later discovers a bug that has been introduced some time between "February" (when the test case worked) and "April" (when it fails), then they might want to diff the source to see what has changed in that time. They will see that the entire codebase is different, which prevents them ever gaining any useful information from diffs. You are effectively defining "Year Zero" for your code base. If nobody ever uses historical diff, then of course the formatting might be more important.

Comment: This case sounds like a very good argument against using a code-formatting tool.  If you insist on using it, then I don't see how you can avoid going through the old and new version of the file, line by line, manually inspecting everything.  No easy way out here.

Comment: Also, merging changes made on a branch with your changes, into a branch without them (or vice-versa), could prove very difficult. It's not just humans which rely on diffing the repository, although some merge tools are smarter than others.

Comment: Steve, You're right!! Historical information will be lost and merging other's changes will be a nightmare! I am having second thoughts now! 
Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I've been on the receiving end of one of these reformats once.  I was looking at how much work it would be to take Altera's Nios II compiler (based on gcc 3.4.1) and upgrade it to 3.4.6.  Altera supplies the source as a giant tarball, not a patch against the gcc source.  So I diffed their tarball against gcc 3.4.1's.  Egads.  Even using the `-b` flag to `diff` to make it ignore all the indentation and LF to CRLF changes, there were still a lot of reformats.  And in the end, all they had changed in most cases was a few real lines of code.  I gave up, and we're moving away from Nios II.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I would *not* check your code into the repo** without thoroughly checking it first (review, testing).

*Pure* formatting changes should not change the object file size, unless you've done a debug build (in which case all bets are off). A release build should be not just the same size, but barring your using `__DATE__` and such to insert preprocessor content, it should be byte-for-byte the same as well.

If the "reformatting" tool has actually done some micro-optimizations for you (caching repeated access to invariants in local vars, or undoing *your* having done that unnecessarily), that might affect the optimization choices the compiler makes, which can have an effect on the object file. But I wouldn't assume that that was the case.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see the diff line by line to see why it is changing the size of the object file.

Answer (score 4):

Brief answer is no:)

Comment: unfortunately, it's also wrong.. :) .. or a little too brief.

Answer (score 3):

if `##__LINE__` macro is used might produce longer strings. How different are the sizes?

(this macro is often hides in new and assert messages in debug.)

Comment: exL
before: 786536 
after: 786504

Comment: Unfortunately this is difficult to ascertain as third party header files I have used might have __LINE__ macro. I'll have to do the hard way of verifying the changes

Comment: That kind of line count difference is small how far out are the obj file differences? have you tried a binary compare of these obj files?

Answer (score 2):

just formatting the code should not change the size of the object file.

Answer (score 1):

It might if you compile with debugging symbols, as it might have added more line number information. Normally it wouldn't though, as has already been pointed out.

Try comparing object files built without debugging symbols.

Comment: I am not using any debugging options :(. So I think I'll have to check the diff line by line and figure out what must've gone wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to find a comparison tool that won't care about the formatting changes (like perhaps "diff--ignore-all-space") and check using that before checking in.